# Auto increment with my own number with alphabet

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do an auto increment `id` at my mySQL as my `id`. And this id will saved in mySQL. Sorry for my poor English; maybe most of you will not understand what im talking about. Let me show an example.

like this:

> abc/def/001(001)until abc/def/001(100)

The auto increment id will auto change to

> abc/def/002(001).

Is this possible to do it?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

(i would like to update my question)

can this possible write with php code or Generator with php code and save into mysql?

Comment: You want an autoincrement every 100 records? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry i read your question the third time, I still don't get it, can you maybe include your `table schema` for that table? I do not get whether the values you mention here (for example `abc/def/001(001)`) represent single values that should be written exactly that way into a column? Or are there multiple columns at work here?

Comment: It's not possible. You don't even need it. It might be the case that you don't even need MySQL if you have the need to glue a string to auto increment (hint: you can prepend the string when you echo out the information, not upon insert).

Comment: yes this id is represent single values for each column

Comment: modified my answer to represent in php.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 columns to achieve that. one of them a normal auto increment integer value, the second one, which is updated whenever a new row is inserted either with a trigger or manually using CONCAT():

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (column1,colum2,column3) VALUES (1,2,3)";
mysqli_query($link,$query);
$last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
$query = "UPDATE table1 SET my_auto_increment = CONCAT('abc/def/', id) WHERE id = '$last_inserted_id'" // where id is an integer auto increment field
mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Comment: Looks like he is looking for something a bit more complicated (second id goes only up to 100, then the first one is incremented), so something like: `CONCAT("abc/def/", floor(id/100), "(", id%100, ")")`.

Comment: I find it odd that you'd provide the solution without even mentioning why this is one of the worst ideas ever. Now someone googling for a silly thing like this will stumble upon here and copypaste your example, then 6 months down the road they'll curse the day they've done it if by any chance their projects is even slightly successful.

Comment: Well, you can't know why he needs that. I recently had a specific request to have an incremental primary key that looks like this: regionalcode.usercode.dataid to be able to parse all that info from one field. i'm not saying it looks pretty, but again nothing always is. Also keep in mind, some projects are pretty successful, even if they are used by just 100 people. not every php/mysql application should be open to public and receives hundreds of thousands of request daily.

Comment: I'm not talking about hundreds of thousands of users, I'm talking about how certain principles in software design should be adhered to. For example, adding string information to PK itself is stupid, by definition. There's a variety of reasons why you want to avoid that, and why it's infinitely better to create another column next to PK that contains that string info. Problem is that we should avoid bad practices, even by advising against them if we can't avoid them on our current projects ourselves.

Comment: he never said that it **should** be PK. he only asks if it can be done autoincremental. my answer is actually advising what you just said. create another column to keep that string value and keep the auto incremental integer primary key intact.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using the MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT`. At least, not directly as you describe. But it's possible to emulate that behavior.

---

But first, as an aside, I question the need for this type of concatenated identifier in the database. It's problematic, and is going to cause more problems and grief down the road, more than you anticipate right now. If I had to include a column like this, I wouldn't make it a primary key.

I strongly advocate surrogate integer keys, because they meet all the desirable aspects of the ideal primary key: simple, unique, anonymous, immutable, et al. There are two schools of thought on surrogate keys: (1) those that think surrogate keys are a really good thing, and (2) those who haven't been burned by choosing a natural key, yet.

I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, or know what your requirements are. But if you do have an option that avoids storing this type of identifier in the database, I strongly recommend you seriously consider availing yourself of that option.

There's good reason that MySQL doesn't natively support generating identifiers like yours. They are trouble prone, cause grief, and are a bad idea.

With that advertisement aside...

---

In order for the database to "automatically" generate the values for that column (that is, if the value for that column is not being provided as a value in a SQL insert statement), then you could define a BEFORE INSERT trigger to generate it for you.

The trigger could make use of an integer AUTO_INCREMENT column to generate unique values, and then use that integer value as part of an expression to generate the character string you need.

This demonstration query shows an expression that will generate the string in the specified format... `i` is the unique integer value, `a` is an expression to generate the first integer, demonstrates how to get the first integer component, `b` is the second integer component, and `val` concatenates that together in the specified format.

```
SELECT t.i
     , (t.i DIV 100 - IF(t.i MOD 100,0,1)) a
     , (t.i MOD 100 + IF(t.i MOD 100,0,100)) b
     , CONCAT('abc/def/'
       ,IF(t.i>100000
         ,(t.i DIV 100 - IF(t.i MOD 100,0,1))
         ,RIGHT(CONCAT('00',(t.i DIV 100 - IF(t.i MOD 100,0,1))),3)
        )
       ,'('
       ,RIGHT(CONCAT('00',(t.i MOD 100 + IF(t.i MOD 100,0,100))),3)
       ,')')
       AS val
  FROM ( SELECT 101 AS i
         UNION ALL SELECT 199
         UNION ALL SELECT 200
         UNION ALL SELECT 201
         UNION ALL SELECT 299
         UNION ALL SELECT 300
         UNION ALL SELECT 301
         UNION ALL SELECT 100000
         UNION ALL SELECT 100001
       ) t
```

Note: to avoid that first integer component from doing a "wrap" for values of `i` greater than 99900, that first component will need to be more than three places.

To put that expression into a trigger to automatically generate the bizarre identifier value, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, val  VARCHAR(80)
);
```

Note that the AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table is defined to be UNSIGNED, so we won't allow negative values. (Our expression above isn't designed to handle values less than 100, since the starting point was specified as "001(001)", we're going to have our algorithm have that correspond to an integer value of 1.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trg_mytable_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
  DECLARE i BIGINT;
  SET i = 100 + NEW.id;
  SET NEW.val = CONCAT('abc/def/'
       ,IF(i > 100000
          ,((i DIV 100) - IF(i MOD 100,0,1))
          ,RIGHT(CONCAT('00',((i DIV 100) - IF((i MOD 100),0,1))),3)
        )
       ,'('
       ,RIGHT(CONCAT('00',(i MOD 100 + IF(i MOD 100,0,100))),3)
       ,')');
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

It's not clear where the 'abc/def' component is coming from. So, I've just hard coded it in the trigger.

If you want to run separate AUTO_INCREMENT integer values for different values of the 'abc/def/', such that you could have 'abc/def/001(001)' and 'ccc/ddd/001(001)'...

the MyISAM engine has a peculiar feature: if the AUTO_INCREMENT column is a secondary column in an index and is not the leading column in any other index, then MySQL will generate auto increment sequences for each distinct value in the leading portion of the index. (I've tested that, but never really used it, because that feature isn't available in the InnoDB engine.)